# Rails not getting average using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm working on learning Active Record and queries and wrote a query within my rails console that I thought should work pretty easily, but it is not.

```
Statistic.select("player_id, sum(oreb)").group("player_id").limit(5)
```

This returns the following Active Record Relation

```
[#<Statistic:0x007f801b2f0240 id: nil, player_id: 1>, #<Statistic:0x007f801b2f00b0 id: nil, player_id: 2>, #<Statistic:0x007f801fcffed0 id: nil, player_id: 3>, #<Statistic:0x007f801fcffd40 id: nil, player_id: 4>, #<Statistic:0x007f801fcffbb0 id: nil, player_id: 5>]
```

oreb does exist, i can use pgAdmin or the psql console tool to execute the query directly

```
Select player_id, sum(oreb) from Statistics
GROUP BY player_id
LIMIT 5
```

And get the a result that includes oreb.

I've done a bit of research, and can't find a simple reason for why this is not working...any thoughts would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model `Statistic` doesn't have column for `sum(oreb)` and can't be mapped to model's attributes but data is retrieved. You can extract it by given name to `sum`.

```
stats = Statistic.select("player_id, sum(oreb) total").group("player_id").limit(5)
puts stats.first.total
```

Comment: Ok, so that's just (as far as I'm concerned ***super weird*** in rails.  That does work, it gives me the total, BUT, if you type `puts stats.first.inspect`, the total value is not there...so now I wanna ask where is it stored?

Comment: It's stored in "sum(oreb)" attribute. Try `Statistic.select("player_id, sum(oreb)").group("player_id").limit(5).first["sum(oreb)"]`

Comment: But, I mean maybe it's my understand of rails is off, shouldn't that show up in the inspect as well?  It could be that I understand inspect wrong? And actually that sample you just put in fails cause it's trying to order by statistics.id

Comment: `inspect` only shows columns that exists in the table. `sub(oreb)` is dynamically generated column.

Comment: Look at `inspect` method implementation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c0c331bfc8ba66efa310c1c065e3b6349d97d9b2/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L246